# Why does upload speed get slower the farther I am from the destination server while download speed remains mostly constant?

Tags: networking, performance, internet, speed, upload

I recently upgraded from 250/40 cable internet to Gigabit down/up fiber internet and have an interesting finding I found recently.

When I'm exchanging traffic from my computer to other remote servers (could be anything really, a remote file sharing server, speedtest server, VPN server etc. I noticed that no matter how far I am from the destination server I can still get a strong download speed (for example I am on the East Coast USA and can easily achieve a download speed of 800Mbps+ even to servers in Australia, but only upload speed of 75-150Mbps) but I noticed that the farther my destination server is from where I am, the slower my upload speed gets. (For example, to a server in the same state as me/nearby states, I can get a speed of 850-900 on both the upload and download, and to other servers elsewhere on the East Coast USA, a bit farther away from me, I can also get around 800-900Mbps on download but upload is a little lower, maybe 600-700Mbps, but to a server more far away from me, one in Europe for example, I can still get a respectable download speed of 800-900, but my upload speed decreases dramatically, I can get an upload speed of 100-150Mbps at most to servers in Europe. Same thing with servers in Asia/Australia and even the other side of the country (West Coast USA). I can almost always get 700-900Mbps download, but upload to these more faraway servers is 100-150Mbps at the maximum.)

I'm curious why this occurs, and I'm nearly certain it isn't some misconfiguration on my end, because a friend of mine who also has the Gigabit plan with the same ISP as I do, but in a different state, also experiences this same phenomenon. So I'm curious whether this is just the nature of how the internet works or if it is something else, I would appreciate it if anyone has some insight on this.

Comment: Personally I'm also curious, since in theory "upload" from your side is just "download" from the server's side – so the internet itself wouldn't really see a difference. _(Maybe it has something to do with the congestion control algorithm your OS uses, and the way it reacts to latency differences?)_

Comment: I suspected The OS had something to do with it as well but I noticed I experience the same thing whether I boot up Windows or Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I recently upgraded my router for unrelated reasons and now I am getting much higher upload speeds over VPN! Apparently my old router could handle Gigabit, but just barely, so for some reason it could not handle high upload speed over VPN.

Answer (score 1):

This will most likely depend on the speed test you use. If it is a eb-based speed test, then the upload part is very likely to consist of fewer connections, maybe even of only one at a time. The download test is nearly always multi-connection.

As latency increases (which is unavoidable with long distances), the number of packtes "on the wire" becomes a limiting factor, so the bandwidth can no longer become saturated by a single connection.

If you use (or create) a test, where the number of connections is high(er) you are likely to see symmetrical(-ish) numbers.